# How can I block or hide my source code, but run it normally. On PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I wanna run the PS script normally, but when I or any other people try open the source code by anyway, you can't open it.

Comment: I think you need to convert your script in a binary module (c#/vb.net) and obfuscate the .dll file because with reflection it's easy find source code. No way IMO for script ps1 files... or try this: http://powergui.org/entry.jspa?externalID=3122

Answer (score 0):

try [PShellExec](http://powergui.org/entry.jspa?externalID=3122) (should use some kind of obfuscation principle)